# Matlab - change intensity of image so brightest values appear black

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Given an image I want to change the intensity of all pixel values over a certain color to black.

```
img = imread('image.tif');
img(x > 200) = 0; %if the pixel is over RGB 200 change to RGB 0
```

Right now the 'x' in img(x > 200) is not a variable but I want some way to gauge the RBG value of each pixel and change it

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img(img > 200)=0;
```

This is a form of logical indexing. Learn more [here](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)